# Rails app docker container not accessible from Windows host

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to make a simple docker container that runs the Rails app from the directory that I launch it in.

Everything appears to be fine except when I run the container and try to access it from my Windows host at the IP address that Docker Machine gives me, it responds with a connection refused error message.

I even used the Nginx Dockerfile as a reference, because the Nginx Dockerfile actually builds a container that is accessible for me.

Here is my Dockerfile so far:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1

RUN gem install rails && \
apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install -y nodejs


VOLUME ["/web_app"]
ADD . /web_app
WORKDIR /web_app

RUN bundle install

CMD rails s -p 80

EXPOSE 80
```

I build the image using this command

```
docker build -t rails_server .
```

I then run it using this command

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 rails_server
```

And here is what I try to access the webpage:

```
curl $(docker-machine ip)
```

And this is what I get back:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 80: Connection refused
```

And this is how it makes me feel:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that the app is listening on 127.0.0.1:80, so the service will not accept connection from outside the container. Could you check if modifying the rails server to listening on 0.0.0.0 the issue solves?

You can do that using the `-b` flag of `rails s`:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1

RUN gem install rails && \
apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install -y nodejs


VOLUME ["/web_app"]
ADD . /web_app
WORKDIR /web_app

RUN bundle install

CMD rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Awesome, that works. But I don't quite understand why. For instance, when I did more Rails development, I could start an app up like normal and my coworkers could hit it from their machines using my LAN IP (192.168.xxx.xxx). I feel like I should be able to connect to my docker VM from my host the same way another computer can connect to me on the LAN.

Comment: Would love to know why localhost (defualt?) didn't work and why this was required.

Answer (score 0):

The port is only exposed to the vm running the docker inside. You have to still expose port 80 of your vm to your local machine so it can connect to it. I think the best approach is making your container to be listened o an optional port like `7070` and then using a simple nginx proxy pass to feed the content to the outside (listening on port 80)